# Recording Video from IP camera using VLC?

Tags: c#, web-applications, vlc

i am try VLC media player to record a video from IP camera. i found this command line to record video from ip camera.

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet http://user:password@ipAddress.com:port/videostream.asf --run-time=120 :demux=dump :demuxdump-file=C:\output_test.avi vlc://quit
```

The command line is working, i can get video with sound from IP camera. The only problems is the recorded video  only can be played using VLC itself, the video also only have information which is only size(KB,MB), the windows cannot get the other information such as video length, size(Width*Height), etc. And the most important is video cannot be played using Window Media Player.

****EDIT**

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy --dummy-quiet http://user:password@ipAddress.com:port/videostream.asf --run-time=120 --sout "#std{access=file,mux=avi,dst="c:\test.avi"}"  vlc://quit
```

using this command, now i got all the video's info and playable using window media player and other players as well, but this time the there is no sound in video.

I'm implementing this in web app. I got the code running fine.

Does anyone here can provide me the correct command line to get working video with sound and also video's information.

i tried searching but cannot find the correct command line(if any). Tried VLC forum but got Error 403.

**note: i am using windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

try transcoding & mux

```
vlc.exe -I dummy --dummy-quiet http://user:password@ipAddress.com:port/videostream.asf --run-time=120 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=avi,dst="c:\test.avi"}
```